# HSV Histogram bins equal zero

Tags: emgucv

I'm trying to create and HSV Histogram using the following code

```
Mat image = new Mat(file, LoadImageType.Color);
int hBins = 16;
int sBins = 16;
int vBins = 16;
RangeF hRange = new RangeF(0F, 180F); 
RangeF sRange = new RangeF(0f, 255f);
RangeF vRange = new RangeF(0f, 255f);

Image<Bgr, Byte> imageSource = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(image.Bitmap);
Image<Hsv, Byte> imageHsv = imageSource.Convert<Hsv, Byte>(); 

DenseHistogram hist = new DenseHistogram(new int[] { hBins, sBins, vBins }, new RangeF[] { hRange, sRange, vRange });
hist.Calculate<byte>(imageHsv.Split(), false, null);
```

Problem is though, that when calling `hist.GetBinValues()`, all the values of the bins are zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After battling with this for a few days, I dumped EMGU and just used OpenCV from c++, and this is giving me the correct HSV bins.

Answer (score 1):

Computing the histogram channel by channel seems to give the expected output:

```
                Mat image = new Mat(file, LoadImageType.Color);

                int hBins = 16;
                int sBins = 16;
                int vBins = 16;

                RangeF hRange = new RangeF(0F, 180F);
                RangeF sRange = new RangeF(0f, 256f);
                RangeF vRange = new RangeF(0f, 256f);

                var imageSource = image.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();

                Image<Hsv, Byte> imageHsv = imageSource.Convert<Hsv, Byte>();
                var hsvChannels = imageHsv.Split();

                DenseHistogram hHist = new DenseHistogram(hBins, hRange);
                DenseHistogram sHist = new DenseHistogram(sBins, sRange);
                DenseHistogram vHist = new DenseHistogram(vBins, vRange);

                hHist.Calculate<byte>(new Image<Gray, Byte>[] { hsvChannels[0] }, false, null);
                sHist.Calculate<byte>(new Image<Gray, Byte>[] { hsvChannels[1] }, false, null);
                vHist.Calculate<byte>(new Image<Gray, Byte>[] { hsvChannels[2] }, false, null);

                var hVals = hHist.GetBinValues();
                var sVals = sHist.GetBinValues();
                var vVals = vHist.GetBinValues();.
```

I can't answer for why your method does not work, though. I see `GetBinValues()` returns an array of 16 ^ 3 values where I would expect it to be 16 * 3 values.

Comment: Actually I expect the histogram to be in 3D space i.e 16^3, I've started using the OpenCV c++ library and it generates the histogram correctly, I assume their is an error in the Emgu library when generating 3d histograms

Comment: I see, glad you got it sorted.